# BCP Import In without Text Qualifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, bcp, double-quotes

I am using the BCP utility to import data to SQL Server 2012. I am importing a text file that is tab delimited. If there is data in my file that contains commas, SQL Server is wrapping the field value in double quotes. How can I avoid SQL Server adding this text qualifier? I want the data to not have these quotations, just like it does in the flat text file.

I would like to avoid using a format file because I am using lots flat text files with great variability.

I also cannot use Bulk Insert because my files are not stored on the server, but a local machine that is connecting via SSMS.

EDIT: My BCP Command:

bcp "[DB].[SCHEMA].[TABLE]" in "PATH\FILE.txt" -F2 -w -S"SERVERSTRING" -U"USERNAME" -P"PASSWORD";

Comment: Share your bcp.exe command, without that, hard to say what is wrong.

Comment: @Greg Added, thanks.

Comment: can you cut/paste a couple rows of data, or the values of a column with the offending data?

Comment: @greg it's simply any field value that contains a comma.